# convert data into openNLP compatible training format

Tags: java, sentiment-analysis, opennlp

I am trying to work on sentiment analysis using openNLP on moview review dataset available here: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/pabo/movie-review-data/ (polarity dataset v2.0)

How can i train document categorizer model in openNLP using this dataset ?

It consists of considerable number of reviews already classified as positive, negative into different folder set.

openNLP needs as input a file with each review on new line with a category label prefix. I am looking for an easy way to convert this dataset into openNLP compatible format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using java, i converted the training dataset into openNLP compatible training format i.e. a categorized dataset and saved it to a file on disk e.g.:

- negative movie did not meet expectations
- positive movie was good

Using above generated training set, trained openNLP documentCategorizer model.

To avoid training model on every execution, save the trained model on disk.

Answer (score 2):

OpenNLP currently don't support the Movie Review format. You can create a script that would convert to it [Training Format](http://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.0/manual/opennlp.html#tools.doccat.training), that would looks like something like this:

```
neg A negative tokenized text. Remove line breaks.
pos A positive tokenized text. Remove line breaks.
```

But in advance the OpenNLP Document Categorizer is not perfect fot the sentiment analysis task. There is a sentiment analysis component under development using OpenNLP at [USCDataScience/SentimentAnalysisParser](https://github.com/USCDataScience/SentimentAnalysisParser).

Comment: I was working on similar approach using java.nio.File instead.